# How to display disk capacity via Samba?

Tags: windows, hard-disk, samba, file-sharing

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with a Samba 3.6.6 server.

The config file:

```
[global]
  encrypt passwords = yes
  log level = 1
  max log size = 1000
  read only = no
  security = user
[A]
  browsable = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  path = /mnt/a
[B]
  browsable = yes
  read only = no
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  path = /mnt/b
```

Under /mnt/a and /mnt/b I have mounted 2TB NTFS drives (sda1 and sda2).
Everything works but when I map those in Windows 8 it doesn't display the capacity under them. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with Windows 8 and nothing to do with the Samba server. I have Server 2008R2, for example and can see the sizes of folders within the share just fine.

[image: ss #1]

If on the otherhand you mean that you're accessing the Samba server via Window Explorer like this `\\sambaserver`, and then expecting to see the properties dialog on the shares from this view show their size, this has never worked in any version of Samba I've ever used.

[image: ss #2]

Comment: The folder files work just fine. The disk CAPACITY does not. I want to see how big the disk is and how much free space is on it.

Comment: If you map it as a drive letter does it work then?

Answer (score 2):

If you map the share as a drive letter you will be able to see the size and free space of the device the Samba server is using for that share.

Comment: Since nobody put it in the answers section.